# Swift 2 get minutes and seconds from double

Tags: time, swift2

I am currently storing time in seconds (for example 70.149 seconds). How would I easily get the minutes and seconds? What I mean is 70.149 seconds is 1min and 10sec. How would I be able to do this easily in swift?

Here is an example of what I want to do.

```
let time:Double = 70.149 //This can be any value
let mins:Int = time.minutes //In this case it would be 1
let secs:Int = time.seconds //And this would be 10
```

How would I do this using Swift 2 OS X (not iOS)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let temp:Int = Int(time + 0.5) // Rounding
let mins:Int = temp / 60
let secs:Int = temp % 60
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Only issue is the rounding. This makes it slightly more then what I need. Apart from that it works great!

Comment: Rounding is optional, just remove the `+ 0.5`.

Comment: That works, however it has one more line of code and an extra variable then @CharlesA answer.

Comment: @iProgram - It is a common practice in coding to avoid doing things more than once. In the CharlesA answer there is a lot of casting and redundant operations, and uses a nonstandard way to duplicate the modulus operation. It doesn't make a difference in such a small code example, but if it were repeated many times, you might see a performance difference. I would vote this as the better answer!

Comment: @YiminRong Thanks for the tim, I shall think about it in the future, so you mean this is more efficient? Also, it looks neater too looking at it again.

Answer (score 3):

This would be a relatively simple solution.  It's worth noting this would truncate partial seconds.  You'd have to use floating point math on the third line and call `trunc()`/`ceil()`/`floor()` on the result before conversion to an `Int` if you wanted control over that.

```
let time:Double = 70.149 //This can be any value
let mins:Int = Int(time) / 60 //In this case it would be 1
let secs:Int = Int(time - Double(mins * 60)) //And this would be 10
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

The date components formatter has lots of advantages when displaying human readable text to a user. This function will take a double.

```
func humanReadable(time:Double) -> String {
    let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
    formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
    formatter.unitsStyle = .full
    if let str = formatter.string(from: time) {
        return str
    }
    return "" // empty string if number fails
}

// will output '1 minute, 10 seconds' for 70.149
```